# Sending input value from grandchild to child and parent element with Typescript React Use Callback method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state, usecallback

---It is Grandchild value that i want to send child component  then Parent component with typescript React ----

```
const [mapDestinationfilter, setmapDestinationfilter] = React.useState<any[]>([]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value
    const Destinationfilter = mapdata?.filter(el => {
      return el.price.amount < value
    })
    setmapDestinationfilter(Destinationfilter)

  }
```

how can I  pass this mapDestinationfilter to child component then to parent component with typescript React hooks ?

Comment: const [mapDestinationfilter, setmapDestinationfilter] = React.useState<any[]>([]); initialize in child component and pass as props into grandchild

Comment: i initialize as this const newfilteredData = React.useCallback(() => {
    updateName();
  }, [])  . then sending data to grandChild compenent   updateName={updateName}

Comment: also it is my grandchild code  
interface IProps { updateName: (arg: any) => void}                                         
  {updateName }: IProps                                                                                                            updateName(mapDestinationfilter)

Comment: But this code does not work @欧阳斌

Comment: @欧阳斌  when i do console.log     to updateName in child component it shows as the below                mobileFilterdData => {
    setmapDestinationfilter(mobileFilterdData);
  }